# How to get data using curl in php?

Tags: php, rest, curl, elasticsearch

I am trying to make a PHP api for this curl request

```
 curl 'http://xx.74.229.xxx:9200/snapdeal_electronics_mobiles_cat/_search' -d '{  "query": {  "match" : { "brand" : "Samsung" } } }'
```

While executing this in teminal I am getting response, but when I try to use it directly in PHP script , it's not working

```
   <?php
function httpGet($url)
{
   $ch = curl_init();

   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
//  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

   $output=curl_exec($ch);

   curl_close($ch);
   return $output;
}

echo httpGet("http://xx.74.229.189:9200/snapdeal_electronics_mobiles_cat/_search' -d '{  "query": {  "match" : { "brand" : "Samsung" } } }");
?>
```

Kindly suggest some solution, it is a get request

Comment: The `httpGet` call has syntax errors. You could use `exec`, http://php.net/manual/en/intro.exec.php, and execute your original code or you could full translate it over to use the PHP CURL functionality.

Comment: It cant be a GET request because you include a POST body with the "-d" switch.

Comment: I am using elasticsearch n for that it has this kind of syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating the curl request incorrectly, it is also a POST request you are attempting not a GET as you include a POST body with the "-d" switch.

You need to seperate the URL from the POST body and pass 2 arguments, one for URL one for POST data like so:

```
<?php
function httpGet($url, $data)
{
   $ch = curl_init();

   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
//  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); //POST data

   $output=curl_exec($ch);

   curl_close($ch);
   return $output;
}

echo httpGet("http://xx.74.229.189:9200/snapdeal_electronics_mobiles_cat/_search",'{  "query": {  "match" : { "brand" : "Samsung" } } }');
?>
```

Comment: Thanks @Daniel , this script is not giving me error but it's unable to respond me with correct output i.e, query is not executing

Comment: Without knowing how the request needs to be built or what type of response there is not much I can do.

Comment: Sorry @Daniel , I rechecked my code and changed it with yours . It was my error n you have given right code .. Thanks